# Is there a way to open a link in a browser window?

Tags: android, android-studio

I currently use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```

It currently opens in my [default browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plhrb.jpg).

But I need it to open [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EEaZ.jpg).

Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: You can use a webview

Comment: "But I need it to open like this" -- what do you mean by that?

Comment: @CommonsWare I want it to open [Like this](https://i.imgur.com/NMxJGHC.jpeg) . It currently opens [Like this](https://i.imgur.com/E7rof96.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open any specific browser application rather then opening the url on default browser. Set component to your implicit intent for an example if you want to open the URL only on chrome application then you can call it like this:

```
String url = "https://www.google.com";
try {
  Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
  i.setComponent("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main");
  i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
  i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
  startActivity(i);
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
  // Google chrome application is not installed in user's phone
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
  startActivity(i);
}
```

Sometimes it may happen that application is not available on user's phone in that case catch the exception and open the default browser.

Comment: I want it to open [like this](https://i.imgur.com/NMxJGHC.jpeg) . It currently opens [like this](https://i.imgur.com/E7rof96.jpg). Sorry for being unclear.